# How do I obtain FNC 3 Barcode 128

Tags: vb6, barcode, barcode-scanner

How do you get FNC 3 in ASCII? I wanted to use that for creating a function when press, configuration will be set from barcode manual.

For example

```
BarCodeComm.Output = Chr$(27) & Chr$(128) & Chr$(29) & "CD000"
```

I assume ASCII 128 might be FNC 3 but it doesn't work as intended, any clues?

---

Update:
I found out my FNC3 is ASCII "201" provided by this link https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode/issues/162 and I tried the barcode image provided, 
so I decided to code shown below

```
BarCodeComm.Output = Chr$(201) & "CD000"
```

Is still doesn't work, I don't think is possible to read and configure scanner function in code specifically for my barcode scanner as it doesn't provide set and end.

If there is anyway to configure in code (any language) for me to reference please do assist. Thanks

Comment: Please refer to the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31322815/2568535

Comment: Duplicate is slightly different. This can be thought of as a question about the format of the data notified from the specific hardware/software.

Answer (score 0):

Accurate specifications depend on the descriptions in the scanner's user manual and programming manual.

Chr$(128) is supposed to indicate FNC3, but possibly the combination of the first three bytes including it probably points to FNC3.

Because Chr$(27) is the ASCII ESC and Chr$(29) is the ASCII GS, both of which are out of the Code 128 code table.

[Code 128 Barcode Table Of Characters](http://www.adams1.com/128table.html)

Please check the user manual and programming manual of the scanner.

Comment: That’s the problem, my barcode scanner doesn’t provide these informations. I just take the barcode and convert from https://online-barcode-reader.inliteresearch.com and it shows {FNC3}AB000. Not sure what to do now, trial and error and eventually given up. Thanks tho

Comment: In that case, you can only create barcode of all the patterns to use, read the barcode you created, and guess the format based on the result.