# Does 1d barcode symbology accepts special characters like degree symbol (°)

Tags: vb.net, bartender

I want to generate 1-d barcode symbology with (°) degree symbol.  if i generate 1-d barcode symbology with ° degree symbol its does not printing.  does (°) degree symbol supports in 1-d barcode symbology.  Can someone answer me with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on type of barcode you want to use.

If you are using a code39 type, you can't insert special char like °, because it can rapresent only first 49 ascii chars.
You need to use a barcode type code128, so you can rapresent all 128 ASCII chars, even special chars.

Comment: I am using barcode type 128, but can't able insert special char °. If i insert degree symbol printer does not prints the barcode.

Comment: This is because char ° is an extended ascii character.
Try look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21475390/encode-extended-ascii-characters-in-a-code-128-barcode

Comment: As you mentioned in the above comment.  After changing the text encoding property of the barcode to "ISO 8859-1"character set. its works for me and printing correctly. :)