# Zxing : How to embed Carriage return in a Code-128 barcode

Tags: zxing, code128

I found in the thread below how to embed extended characters in a Code128 barcode by using the Zxing lib. 
[Encode extended ASCII characters in a Code 128 barcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21475390/encode-extended-ascii-characters-in-a-code-128-barcode)

But how can i embed the Carriage Return character (Hex 0x0d) in a Code 128 ?

Comment: 0x0D is equal to 13 in base 10. For your Code128 bar code, I think the carriage return would be written `~013`

Comment: ~013 is seen as standard ASCII characters in the zxing library.